# CheckBox not working with jQuery autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, autocomplete

I am using jQuery's autocomplete plugin to create checklist.
Had a series of problems but thankfully got solutions for all but 1.
My problem left is that when I click on any checkbox it doesnt retain its state . 
Also i want to check the checkbox if list item is clicked.

HTML:

```
<input type='text' id='inTestField' name ='inTestField' />
<input type='hidden' id='TestField' name ='TestField' />
```

JS:

```
var cache = {},lastXhr,selectedItems;
var autoComplete = jQuery( '#inTestField').autocomplete
({
    minLength: 1,
    source : function( request, response ) {
        var term = request.term;
        type:'post';
        // ajax request to server

    },
    delay: 800,
    autoSelect :true,
    open: 
        function( event, ui ){
        selectedItems = new Array();
    }
});
autoComplete.data('autocomplete').menu.options.selected = function(event, ui) { 
    var item = ui.item.data( 'item.autocomplete' ); 
    if(!(item.value == '')){
        selectedItems.push(item.value);
        selectedItems = selectedItems.filter(function(elem, pos, self) {
            return self.indexOf(elem) == pos;
        });
        document.getElementById('TestField').value = selectedItems;
        jQuery(this).val(selectedItems.length + 'items selected'); 
    }
    autoComplete.focus(); 
    return false;
};
autoComplete.data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
    return jQuery( "<li></li>" )
    .data( 'item.autocomplete', item )
    .append( '<a><input type="checkbox" id="autoCheck_'+item.value+'"  />&nbsp;&nbsp;' + item.label + '</a>' )
    .appendTo( ul );
};
```

[image]

Please suggest any changes required
Thanks in advance

Comment: so many views but no reply.
Please help me friends...

Comment: no.i removed autocomplete and used my custom code..